# How to inherit the background color of textarea from parent element in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, textarea, background-color

Consider the following example: ([Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rxNuq/))

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background-color: #777;
}
textarea {
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

I would like the `textarea` to inherit the background color from the wrapper.

It works well in Firefox.

But, in Internet Explorer 7, the background color is white. Why ?

How could I fix that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE7 does not support `inherit` for any properties besides `direction` and `visibility`.

[Source](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritvalue).

You could set the `textarea`'s `background-color` to `transparent` instead.